# Why can't I reset the value of input when click button clear filter on Telerik Grid (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

Step1:

[image]

Step2: After I click the Clear filter button:

[image]

I want reset value input after click lear filter button, but "0.00" is still shown.

Comment: what is your mean when you say: "reset value" , if you want to set the value to zero , then you can write: `numericUpDown1.Value = 0;` , and if you want to hide the value inside control `numericUpDown1`  you can write this after setting value : `numericUpDown1.ResetText();`

Comment: I want to value=" " when clear filter! I will try your suggest. Thank you so much!

Comment: numericUpDown1.Value is integer and can't be a null string.